# Rx Buffer running once and complete

Tags: c#, reactive-programming, system.reactive, reactiveui

I like to collect the first values of a stream for 3 seconds and connect them to another stream of the same datatype. The first Observable is a separate, finished data chunk which should complete in any case, so that I can connect first and second using Concat(). Using Concat() is required keeping the integrity of the data stream.

```
            private IObservable<3DPoints> _1stBuffer = Observable.Empty<3DPoints>();
            ..

           _1stBuffer = someRawStreamObservableReceivingOnNext
                .Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3), 100)
                .Where(item => item.Any())
                .SelectMany(item => item);


// later 
            var streamObservable = _1stBuffer.Concat(_some2ndStream); // doesn't emit, since 1stBuffer doesn't complete
```

I tried this:

```
            _1stBuffer = someRawStreamObservableReceivingOnNext

                // completes the observable, but i want the buffer so far, no emptiness !
                .TimeOut(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3), Observable.Empty<3DPoints>)

                .Buffer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(3), 100)
                .Where(item => item.Any())
                .SelectMany(item => item);
```

The timeout makes the bufferObservable performing Concat(), but continuing Observable.Empty<3DPoints> is no option. How can I fetch the 1st buffer filled for 3 seconds, and Concat them ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're probably looking for one of the [`Take`](http://introtorx.com/Content/v1.0.10621.0/05_Filtering.html#SkipAndTake) variants:

- `source.Take(1)` will take the first element from source, then complete.
- `source.TakeUntil(otherObservable)` will take from source until the first element of otherObservable emits.